# How to get ddl auto generated script in Spring boot JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to quickly get initial SQL script for the database that is being generated by hibernating through ddl-auto property?

I would like to get an initial SQL script for the flyway as a quick start.

Comment: `quickly get initial SQL script` means ?

Comment: ddl auto generates table creation scripts. I need those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use property  `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` and it will print all script on console in format.

[image: hibernate scripts on console]

2. use `ddl-auto` as you did and take backup of schema for your respective DB and use that as initial script

example - [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) , [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/backup.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can see the DDL script generated by Hibernate in a Spring boot application by setting the logging level of Hibernate to debug mode in the application.properties file of your project.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Comment: I tried this before. It doesn't seem to appear in logs

Comment: It works when the tables are created for the first time in DB with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update/create. Also, only keeping spring.jpa.hiberate.show-sql=true does not show me DDL queries that's why I keep the above-mentioned property as well.